How to remove the first letter from each alphanumeric string in a column?
I have a list of 107 alphanumeric serial numbers that have an extra "S" as the first character that I want to remove.
For example, if a serial number is:
SFNS28O413AD

It would become:
FNS28O413AD

There was a function in Excel that removed the first character if you selected the whole columm, but I can't find anything similar in Google Sheets.


REGEXREPLACE

Formulas assume serial numbers are in Column A. Change A:A to match your actual data range.
REGEXEXTRACT uses a regular expression to find "S" at the start of a string and replaces it with an empty value (nothing) if found.
Regular expression syntax:

^ indicates the start of the string
?i makes the match case insensitive.
| is the boolean "or" symbol



Case Insensitive
Replaces "S" regardless if uppercase or lowercase:

Using ?i
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"(?i)^s",))  


 Using |
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"^s|S",))



Case Sensitive
Shorter formula but only replaces "S" if the case matches:

 Uppercase
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"^S",))  


 Lowercase
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"^s",))  



